# Django Rest Framework return a single field from ForeignKey relationship

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have two models in Django like so:

```
 class Project(models.Model):
     title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
     client = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
     ...


 class Task(models.Model):
     title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
     project = models.ForeignKey(Project)
     ...
```

My serializer.py

```
class TaskSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):

    project = serializers.RelatedField(
        source='project'
    )

    client = ?

    # I want to return just the project.client field

    class Meta:
        model = Task
        fields = (
            'id', 'project', 'title', 'client'
            ...
        )
```

Comment: check this to modify your serializers according to your need http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations

Comment: I still don't see how I can get a single field value for a reverse relationship.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The DRF `source` argument for fields supports dotted paths. (see [the docs](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields#core-arguments))

So your `client`-field would be:

```
client = serializers.RelatedField(
    source='project.client'
)
```

Comment: Oh thanks! This does work. However I actually ended up using a separate `serializer` for the the `Project` fields I required (id, title, client), as I though this was better structure for the json object. So when the `TaskSerializer` object is returned, `client` would be available as `project.client`, making it clear where this field comes from. Thanks for the answer.